# Win2016, what triggered a scheduled task?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task with multiple triggers, on event and once every hour. this task can also start with the powershell `Start-ScheduledTask` cmdlet, or with right-click | Run in the Scheduled Task GUI.

is there a way to programmatically find what triggered/ started the task ?